# Crash on UserDefaults with @ character

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I app crashed on this line of code

`let test = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "@")`

This looks like an Apple issue, `UserDefaults` does not seem to accept a key which starts with `@`

Does anyone come across this issue and have a solution for it?

This is the error message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<NSUserDefaults 0x6100000443b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'
```

Comment: That is an odd bug. Curious, why do you need to? Definitely file a radar bug with Apple.

Comment: @picciano No need for a radar. It's not a bug in Apple's code.

Comment: @picciano `@` is reserved character in `value(forKey:)`/`value(forKeyPath:)`, it's used as prefix for [KVC operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are misusing key-value coding. Do not use `value(forKey:)` unless you have clearly understand need to use key-value coding to get data from user defaults. The `@` symbol has special meaning in key-value coding.

The proper solution is to use the `object(forKey:)` method:

```
let test = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "@")
```

or one of the more specific methods for reading data from `UserDefaults` depending on the data type of the stored data.